# Why Slardar's Amplify and Gondar's Track doesnt stack?

Tags: dota-2, dota

I was playing slardar yesterday with gondar in my team. when i amplified a tracked hero the track buff dispelled. Why?

Comment: I'm going to leave this open, but try and rephrase just a little and perhaps elaborate. You'll likely get better responses that way.

Comment: Seems pretty straightforward to me, I don't know what everyone's issue is.

Comment: @Michel I dont understand why you removed the dota tag. Im Tagging it again

Comment: Could be a bug, Gondar's track use to debuff armour but recently changed. Now it only gives vision + extra gold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These spells are likely based off the same WC3 spell (which one I don't know, exactly).

Many spells that have the same base will not stack with each other for legacy reasons. These seem to slowly be in the process of being weaned out as they're antiquated and basically just rote memorization, but for now they remain.

Comment: You are correct bro. And the spell is "Faerie Fire iirc"